# How to render 600px image in 320px screen of iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to show an image of size 600px in a 320px screen,does anyone know how can I do this using code in iPhone, Please help me.

Comment: change the @property(nonatomic) UIViewContentMode contentMode property of the image view and you can fit any sized image in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Here are some short [code snippets](http://www.iphoneexamples.com/).